# Type level programming to represent multidimensional arrays (Tensors)

Tags: arrays, haskell, multidimensional-array, type-level-computation, tensor

I would like to have a type to represent multidimensional arrays (Tensors) in a type safe way. so I could write for example: `zero :: Tensor (5,3,2) Integer`
that would represent a multidimensional array that has 5 element , each of which has 3 elements each of which have 2 elements, where all elements are `Integer`s

How would you define this type using type level programming?

**Edit**:

After the wonderful answer by Alec, Which implemented this using `GADT`s,

I wonder if you could take this a step further, and support multiple implementations of a `class Tensor` and of the operations on tensors and serialization of tensors

such that you could have for example:

- `GPU` or `CPU` implementations using `C`
- pure `Haskell` implementations
- implementation that only prints the graph of computation and does not compute anything
- implementation which caches results on disk
- parallel or distributed computation
- etc...

All type safe and easy to use.

My intention is to make a library in Haskell much like `tensor-flow` but type-safe and much more extensible, using [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) ([ad library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad)), and [exact real arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) ([exact-real library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exact-real))

I think a functional language like `Haskell` is much more appropriate for these things (for all things in my opinion) than the python ecosystem which sprouted somehow.

- Haskell is purely functional, much more sutible for computational programming than python
- Haskell is much more efficient than python and can be compiled to binary
- Haskell's laziness (arguably) removes the need to optimize the computation graph, and makes code much simpler that way
- much more powerful abstractions in Haskell

Although i see the potential, i'm just not well versed enough (or smart enough) for this type-level programming, so i don't know how to implement such a thing in Haskell and get it to compile.

That's where I need your help.

Comment: You may look into [Data.FixedList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/Data-FixedList.html) library to define a type depending on lists with fixed length.

Comment: Some possibly relevant links: https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-1.html https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-2.html https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/67f4mw/naperian_tensors/ Also the vector-sized package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized

Comment: Please also check out Mike Izbicki's work on the [linear-algebra part of `subhask`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/subhask-0.1.1.0/docs/SubHask-Algebra-Vector.html) (he does a lot of machine learning etc., so this might be relevant if you want to go in the direction of TensorFlow), and my [linearmap-category](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#g:5) (which defines tensors in a completely basis-agnostic way, and never talks about _dimensions_ but about _vector spaces_ – these can also be infinite-dimensional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way ([here is a complete Gist](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/adfccb491f9b1df19426566003c6e1a5)). We stick to using Peano numbers instead of GHC's type level `Nat` just because induction works better on them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds, DataKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Foldable
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJClass

data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- Some type synonyms that simplify uses of 'Nat'
type N0 = Z
type N1 = S N0
type N2 = S N1
type N3 = S N2
type N4 = S N3
type N5 = S N4
type N6 = S N5
type N7 = S N6
type N8 = S N7
type N9 = S N8

-- Similar to lists, but indexed over their length
data Vector (dim :: Nat) a where
  Nil    :: Vector Z a
  (:-)   :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a

infixr 5 :-

data Tensor (dim :: [Nat]) a where
  Scalar :: a -> Tensor '[] a
  Tensor :: Vector d (Tensor ds a) -> Tensor (d : ds) a
```

To display these types, we'll use the `pretty` package (which comes with GHC already).

```
instance (Foldable (Vector n), Pretty a) => Pretty (Vector n a) where
  pPrint = braces . sep . punctuate (text ",") . map pPrint . toList

instance Pretty a => Pretty (Tensor '[] a) where
  pPrint (Scalar x) = pPrint x

instance (Pretty (Tensor ds a), Pretty a, Foldable (Vector d)) => Pretty (Tensor (d : ds) a) where
  pPrint (Tensor xs) = pPrint xs
```

Then here are instances of `Foldable` for our datatypes (nothing surprising here - I'm including this only because you need it for the `Pretty` instances to compile):

```
instance Foldable (Vector Z) where
  foldMap f Nil = mempty

instance Foldable (Vector n) => Foldable (Vector (S n)) where
  foldMap f (x :- xs) = f x `mappend` foldMap f xs


instance Foldable (Tensor '[]) where
  foldMap f (Scalar x) = f x

instance (Foldable (Vector d), Foldable (Tensor ds)) => Foldable (Tensor (d : ds)) where
  foldMap f (Tensor xs) = foldMap (foldMap f) xs
```

Finally, the part that answers your question: we can define `Applicative (Vector n)` and `Applicative (Tensor ds)` similar to how `Applicative ZipList` is defined (except `pure` doesn't return and empty list - it returns a list of the right length).

```
instance Applicative (Vector Z) where
  pure _ = Nil
  Nil <*> Nil = Nil

instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector (S n)) where
  pure x = x :- pure x
  (x :- xs) <*> (y :- ys) = x y :- (xs <*> ys)


instance Applicative (Tensor '[]) where
  pure = Scalar
  Scalar x <*> Scalar y = Scalar (x y)

instance (Applicative (Vector d), Applicative (Tensor ds)) => Applicative (Tensor (d : ds)) where
  pure x = Tensor (pure (pure x))
  Tensor xs <*> Tensor ys = Tensor ((<*>) <$> xs <*> ys)
```

Then, in GHCi, it is pretty trivial to make your `zero` function:

```
ghci> :set -XDataKinds
ghci> zero = pure 0
ghci> pPrint (zero :: Tensor [N5,N3,N2] Integer)
{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! thx, But could we go one step further in the abstraction? let's say i want to have multiple implementation of tensor data structures and operations, could this approach work with a type class?

Comment: @user47376 Your edit changes the question a fair bit. :) Yes, it is possible to make this type-class based instead of GADT-based. That approach turns out to be pretty hairy. I instead recommend you try annotating `Vector` and `Tensor` with a type to specify its runtime representation (see how `repa` does this for [its `Array` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:Array) - more information on the possible representations is at the top of the linked page).

Comment: What do you mean by that? Run time type information makes it not type safe, the whole point is to make the compiler check the correctness of the dimensions, or am I missing your point ?

Comment: What makes the type class implementation "hairy"? Is it really so difficult to go from: `zero :: Tensor '[3,5,4]` to `zero :: Tensor '[3,5,4] a => a`

Comment: @user47376 repa has type encoded information that tells you what the underlying representation is - delayed, unboxed, etc. The hairiness is that you end up defining multiple data types for what were otherwise just disjuncts of the GADT.